# DocuSign, unable to upload templates from different accounts

Tags: templates, upload, permissions, docusignapi

I am unable to upload template from one account to another (dev <---> production) as I keep getting the error message "Unable to transform template 'some template name' This account lacks sufficient permissions. SAML Authentication is not permitted." Now I have uploaded templates on both accounts before and I am an admin on both accounts. Is there some option I need to activate to be able to upload per template? Please advise. By the way, this template is shared and was created by someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a feature enabled in your dev sandbox that's not enabled in your production account- the SAML authentication feature.  If you are simply interested in getting the template transferred then try what I've listed below.  Otherwise contact your DocuSign Account Manager, show them the error message, and ask them to enable SAML authentication in your production account (assuming you're account plan covers that feature).

1. Login to developer sandbox account at demo.docusign.net.
2. Go to Manage -> Templates and download the template in question.
3. Open the *.xml template file you just downloaded locally in an editor.
4. Review the `<recipient >` settings in the template and remove any SAML settings.

The recipient section might be located after the PDF bytes further down in the file, and might look something like this:

```
<Recipients>
     <Recipient>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <UserName />
        <Email />
        <Type>Signer</Type>
        <AccessCode />
        <RequireIDLookup>false</RequireIDLookup>

        <SAMLAuthentication>
           <SAMLAttributes />
        </SAMLAuthentication>

        <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
        <Note />
        <RoleName>NDA_Signer</RoleName>
        <TemplateLocked>false</TemplateLocked>
        <TemplateRequired>false</TemplateRequired>
        <SignInEachLocation>false</SignInEachLocation>
     </Recipient>
</Recipients>
```

After removing the SAMLAuth settings try uploading the template again into your production account and that should work.

Comment: I tried again after a couple of days and I was able to upload. Not really sure why that happened, but I will keep what you have written in mind. Thank you for your response.